# Jquery Autocomplete ignore dash on search

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete that is working for any combination of letters that you type in to the input field.  But now I want it to ignore the dash in the result that I am searching.

I type in the input box

ea1

it will find

ea-1

Autocomplete code

```
$("#customer"+myIndex).autocomplete({
         source: "AS_userLookup.cfm",
         select: function(e, ui){
```

My database query

```
 SELECT roomname        
 From sec_rooms_new
 where lower(roomname) like '%#lcase(url.term)#%' and dontshow = 0
```

Would I do it in the jquery or would I do it in the db query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your query to this:

```
SELECT
    roomname        
FROM
    sec_rooms_new
WHERE
    REPLACE(LOWER(roomname), '-', '') LIKE '%#lcase(url.term)#%'
    AND dontshow = 0
```

The `REPLACE` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) replaces any occurrence of `-` with an empty string. This means `ea-1` becomes `ea1` and is therefore returned when you search for `ea1`.

It might be slow to use this query, because every time you execute it the database will apply the `REPLACE` and `LOWER` functions on the value of `roomname` of all your rows. It might be better to create an extra column where you store the prepared value of `roomname` (so with the `REPLACE` and `LOWER` functions already applied). Then you can search on this columnn, which will be much faster.

One more thing: depending on your settings (column type and charset) `LIKE` might already be case insensitive. This means you can remove the `LOWER` function from your `WHERE` statement, which will make the query faster. Read more about it in the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this, but had the "ALL" in the replace kept erroring.

Comment: Keep in mind that this query will not scale up. as the table size grows, this query will run slower and slower.

Comment: @user1253239 I don't see `ALL` in the replace. Does it work now or do I misinterpret your comment?

Comment: @Yisroel True, I was already adding a paragraph about that. It's now in the answer.

Comment: FYI - keep in mind that "ALL" is for the _ColdFusion_ replace function - whereas in  the query above you are using the SQL "Replace" function... 2 different animals. One comes with an option for "ALL" and other does not :)